# how to return a c# object to javascript (mvc2)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, uploadify

I'm realizing an imageupload in MVC2. I've realized the imageupload with uplpadify:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
           $('#FileInput').uploadify({
               'uploader': '../../../../Scripts/swf/uploadify.swf',
               'script': '/Market/RR/BildUpload',
               'cancelImg': '../../../../Content/images/cancel.png',
               'folder': '//Uploades/RR/',
               'auto': true,
               'sizeLimit': 102400,
               'removeCompleted': false,
               'fileExt': '*.jpg;*.gif;*.png',
               'fileDesc': 'Image Files',
               'multi': true,
               'onComplete': function (event, queueID, fileObj, response, data) {
                   var fname = response;        
               }
           });             
</script>
```

The controler saves the image:

```
public Bilder BildUpload()
        {

            Bilder b = new Bilder();

            if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
            {

                file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(@"\Uploads\Horses\images\full\") + id + f.Extension);

                b.Pfad =  host + id + f.Extension;
                b.ID_Bild = Convert.ToInt16(id);

                return b;
            }
            else
            {
                return b;
            }     
        }
```

But how to get the value of my returned object Bild? I have tried things like `result.Pfad`
But it does not work.
Do you have any ideas how to solve this problem?
Thanks!!!

Comment: What is your response and data in your oncomplete handler ?

Comment: I'm honest: this part I have copied from http://www.uploadify.com/forums/discussion/26/how-to-send-filename-to-another-pagescript/p1, if I make a alert(response); the result is: "f.viewmodel.Bilder". If I do the same with data the result is "Object[objekt]".

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried returning a JSONResult() or a Content(), passing in the value of the file name you want to return back to the ajax caller?